# Não consigo fazer layout fluido no menu

Tags: css, css3

Olá.

Tenho o menu abaixo:

```
<ul class="menuUlTopo">
  <li class="menuTopo"><a href="principal.php" title="Principal">Principal</a></li>
  <li class="menuTopo"><a href="administradoresMenu.php" title="Administradores">Administradores</a></li>
  <li class="menuTopo"><a href="clientesMenu.php" title="Clientes">Clientes</a></li>
  <li class="menuTopo"><a href="imoveisMenu.php" title="Imóveis">Imóveis</a></li>
  <li class="menuTopo"><a href="tiposMenu.php" title="Tipos de Imóveis">Tipos de Imóveis</a></li>
  <li class="menuTopo"><a href="emails.php?acao=listar" title="E-mails">E-mails</a></li>
</ul>
```

Gostaria de torná-lo fluido. Mas, por mais que altere o css não consigo fazer os ítens do menu cairem para baixo do outro quando diminuimos o tamanho da tela.

Onde estou errando?

Eis o css

```
a, a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}

ul.menuUlTopo {
    width: 100%;
}

ul li.menuTopo {
    float:left;
    width:161px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border-left: #005E9C 1px solid; 
    border-right: #005E9C 1px solid;    
}

ul li.menuTopo a {
    width:161px;
    height:50px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;  
    color: #FFF;
}

ul li.menuTopo:hover {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Grato a quem puder ajudar

Answer (score 0):

É necessário que a largura dos elementos seja estática, se você usar porcentagem, os itens irão diminuir para se adaptar ao tamanho da janela. Apenas o `ul.menuTopo` deve ter a largura como porcentagem.

Comment: Outro problema é que as li's estão descendo acompanhando o layout fluido mas os links a e a:hover permanecem em suas posições não acompanhando as li's. O que fazer?

Comment: Você pode colocar da forma que está fazendo no http://jsfiddle.net por favor?

Comment: Ok. Esta aí: https://jsfiddle.net/hnzajwwq/

Comment: O :hover precisa ser definido para o elemento 'a', e não na li. E o 'background-color' deve ser definido no 'a', já que você colocou altura fixa na ul. 

Corrigi e fiz update: 
https://jsfiddle.net/hnzajwwq/2/

Comment: ok ndeu certo. Agora me diga uma coisa: para se centralizar as li's verticalmente é mesmo necessário usar display:table-cel?

Comment: Outra coisa: as caixas das li's e dos links não estão se ajustando ao tamanho da tela. Apenas estão descendo. É assim mesmo?

Comment: Bem, você pode colocá-los como porcentagem e definir um min-width constante, depende do seu layout

Comment: Não entendi! Pode explicar melhor fazendo favor?

Comment: Exemplificando: https://jsfiddle.net/hnzajwwq/4/

Comment: Ok. Mas nesse exemplo os textos não estão alinhados verticalmente: mddle.

Comment: Para isso podemos usar o line-height. Assim: https://jsfiddle.net/hnzajwwq/5/